# Bash arrays declared as local to user-defined function

Tags: bash

Can bash arrays be declared local inside user-defined functions ?  Have been convinced that bash arrays always have global scope.

Comment: See: `help declare | grep local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an array can be local to a function.  Declare it inside the function with the `local` keyword.  Here's an example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

global_ary=( one two )

function my_func () {
  local local_ary=( three four )
  echo "In my_func function:"
  echo "global_ary: ${global_ary[@]}"
  echo "local_ary: ${local_ary[@]}"
  echo
}

echo "In main script:"
echo "global_ary: ${global_ary[@]}"
echo "local_ary: ${local_ary[@]}"
echo

my_func

echo "In main script again:"
echo "global_ary: ${global_ary[@]}"
echo "local_ary: ${local_ary[@]}"
echo
```

The above script populates a global array, and a function with a local array.  It prints the contents of the two arrays before, during, and after the function has been invoked.  The output looks like this:

```
In main script:
global_ary: one two
local_ary:

In my_func function:
global_ary: one two
local_ary: three four

In main script again:
global_ary: one two
local_ary:
```

The global array is available in the main script and in the function, as you would expect.  The local array is only available in the function, so only the `echo "local_ary: ${local_ary[@]}"` in the function shows its contents.

As an experiment, you can change the `local` keyword to `declare` or remove it (leaving the line as `local_ary=( three four )`).  This results in the `local_ary` variable being created as global rather than local.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fun ()
{
    local a=( 1 2 3 )
    echo local "${a[@]}"
}

fun

echo global "${a[@]}" # empty
```